# Converting json string to JSONArray in java?

Tags: java, json

I have this json string returned from a 3rd party api

```
{"msg":"xff","uuid":"44037b67-3629-4325-83e5-7a00cb78dfdf"}
```

When I try to parse it by the below code

```
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(message.toString());
  JSONArray arr  = json.getJSONArray(0);

  String mess = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("msg");
  String uuid    = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("uuid");
  System.out.println("message : "+mess);
  System.out.println("uuid    : "+uuid);
```

I get this below exception

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"msg":"xff","uuid":"44037b67-3629-4325-83e5-7a00cb78dfdf"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

What other way can I parse it?

Comment: First understand the difference between a JSON Object and a JSON Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSONObject` instead:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
String mess = obj.getString("msg");
String uuid = obj.getString("uuid");
System.out.println("message : "+mess);
System.out.println("uuid    : "+uuid);
```